# Detect Active Typing in React Search Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

Title pretty much says it all.  So far the best I have been able to come up with is creating this `isTyping` method on the search bar component like this:

```
  isTyping = debounce(() => {
    console.log('typing...');
    const callback = () => window.setTimeout(() => this.setState({ typing: false }), 500);
    this.setState({ typing: true }, callback);
  }, 500)
```

and I am calling this method from the `onChange` event handler on the search input text component.  It's not working though.  For some reason, the log 'typing' keeps occurring after I stop typing and the function is not setting state of typing to true in the middle of the call like I was hoping.

```
<div className="fancysearch">
          <TextInput
            ref          = "input"
            type         = "text"
            name         = "query"
            placeholder  = { placeholder }
            label        = ""
            className    = "form-control"
            defaultValue = { query }
            onChange     = {this.isTyping}
          />
          <b></b>
        </div>
```

Comment: "For some reason, the log 'typing' keeps occurring after I stop typing" - isn't the very idea of debounce to do something after the function hasn't been called for specified time?

Comment: Debounce should not call the function if it was called x seconds before.  Therefore the log should fire once at the very beginning of typing and not after that since it is being debounced.

Comment: I don't know your implementation of `debounce`, but the behavior you describe may depend on the `immediate` parameter being set to `true` - at least that's the case in implementations that come up while searching the web.

Comment: hm using lodash debounce, and I don't think that one takes an immediate param

Comment: It does: "[options.leading=false] (boolean): Specify invoking on the leading edge of the timeout.". So `isTyping = _.debounce( ()=>{ ... }, 500, { leading: true })`